# Returning unused values from a list in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

folks

I'm a tester who is new to SQL.  I'm testing an application where every time I use it I have to enter a value.  For good testing, I can only use every value once, and I have to use a limited range of values.  But my coworkers and I randomly used these values before.

So, let's say I've got `1834, 1835, 1836...` down to `2000`.  `1850...1900` is taken.  But, `1850...1900` has each created a row in the `ATTR` table under the `ID_TX` column.

I know enough to `FIND * FROM ATTR WHERE ID_TX BETWEEN 1834 AND 2000;`

This returns all used values, which means I still have to change the list to remove those values.

I've tried `WHERE NOT EXIST`, but that either shows me every `ID_TX` that isn't in that list, or doesn't show me anything.

My question is, is there any way to query either using `BETWEEN` or using a `IN` list to return all numbers that aren't existing in the database from a list not stored in the database?  If there is no simple way with queries in a worksheet, is this something I can do with PLSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query to generate the numbers and then use `MINUS` to remove the existing numbers:

```
SELECT LEVEL + 1833
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (2000 - 1833)
MINUS
SELECT ID_TX
FROM   ATTR
WHERE  ID_TX BETWEEN 1834 AND 2000;
```

Comment: Thank you, MTO. I found out that ID_TX was being stored as a varchar, so I had to use to_number(trim(replace(ID_TX,'.',','))), but this did exactly what I wanted.